# error in every project after sdk and adt update!

Tags: android

Ok I updated eclipse ADT plain and the SDK platforms and it gave all of my current projects errors. If I click in the project there are no errors with in the projects files but an error on the actual project file. Thinly happen after I updated.what am I suppose do now?!?

Example

App1  -  error

Src - no error

Gen - no error

Res - no error

Manifest - no error

Comment: What errors are shown in the problem view?
(to open the problems view click on window -> show view -> Problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the project?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after reinstall eclipse i realized i had the debug certificate expired. You do not need to reinstall eclipse but you just have to delete the expired certificate. The certificate is located at $HOME/.android/ directory and is called "debug.keystore".

After deleting restart eclipse and thats it because another certificate is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning didn't work for me at first.  I was able to solve it by deleting all of the files inside the "bin" directory of each project that had an error and then cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

or, try to check preferences->Android->SDK location.
In some case, Android sdk requires higher version of ADT.
Refer to this link:
[This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or above. .... Please update ADT to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227335/this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-14-0-0-or-above)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select any of your projects
2. Click on problems tab above console output window
3. Select everything in it and then delete it
4. Rebuild that project by right clicking the project