# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or above. .... Please update ADT to the latest version

Tags: android, sdk, adt

Please help me with fixing the following error:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or above.  
Current version is 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.  Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

I am facing this error problem when I am using Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: won't let me use Android SDK, wrongly claims my ADT is out of date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852823/eclipse-wont-let-me-use-android-sdk-wrongly-claims-my-adt-is-out-of-date)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that you have updated android sdk but your android adt plugin is not up to date. So updating your Eclipse plugin would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 68):

This error happens due to an incompatibility between ADT and SDK.

To fix it:

1. Eclipse > Help
2. Install New Software
3. Add [this](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) to Work With section and press enter
4. After developer tools appears on the list, check it and click Next
5. Restart eclipse once download is finished

Similar problem was already discussed here: [Eclipse: won't let me use Android SDK, wrongly claims my ADT is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852823/eclipse-wont-let-me-use-android-sdk-wrongly-claims-my-adt-is-out-of-date)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked for me with the new bundle and 2.6.2 ADT plugin.

Comment: +! for this answer :)

Comment: np lad, glad that I could help

Comment: Still a working solution with the latest ADT ver. 23 and above to upgrade from ver 22.xx.

Answer (score 6):

1. In Eclipse go to Help.
2. Select the "Install New Software" menu item.
3. From this dialog, click the "Add..." button. This will bring up a new, smaller dialog.
4. Enter the Name "ADT" and Location: "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
5. after loading you will get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
6. check both if you want or check Developer Tools.
7. click Next
8. Accept licenses, and Finish

Answer (score 6):

if you don't want to update your ADT version, you can do this for fix your problem.

modify ${android-sdk}/tools/lib/plugin.prop **plugin.version** to your current version, restart eclipse.

```
# begin plugin.prop
plugin.version=22.3.0
# end plugin.prop
```

enjoy it.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. @Amon Olimov

Answer (score 5):

For those of you who are experiencing this problem:

Eclipse says the ADT needs an update
-You click to check for updates
-It tells you there are no updates

You need to run Eclipse as administrator. This will immediately fix the problem.

Comment: If this works, it's 100x a better solution than the one that's been accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse -> Help -> Check for updates

Check 'Android Development Tools' and install the update

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the version of the ADT plugins in Eclipse are paired to a specific SDK version. It's not very well documented, but if you update one at any point, you need to update the other. The version number of the tools and the plugins are usually in sync, but in some cases, they aren't. In fact, right now (June 27) the SDK is version 19 and the plugins are 18. Of course, that will change later today when Google IO starts. The intent is to keep the version numbers in sync, but it doesn't always work out that way.

You can get the older versions of ADT and/or the SDK from the Android tools site. In some cases, you have to figure out the secret for the URL to directly download the older packages, but they are there.

It shouldn't be necessary though. The plugins and the SDK work with all prior versions of the platform, so you should always be safe installing the latest SDK and plugins directly from the Android Developers site.